# Developing a swipe and view change iPhone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am trying to develop an application whose view closely matches with groupon app. User should be able to swipe on the screen and the entire screen changes with top pointer pointing to different tool bar entity.

Any pointer of how to go about it?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [UIScrollView Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html) and [PageControl Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html) from Apple Guides

Hope it helps,
**Mário**

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a pagecontrol+scrollerview
The complex part is making the toolbar elements move  when you are changing the page at a different speed